# Таблица - справочник для столбца с Null значениями

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, где присутствует поле Sold. В нем проставляются значения от 1 до 4, но так же может быть проставлено Null. Для этого поля решили сделать таблицу справочник. Вопрос - можно ли создать связь между ними, если в поле Sold присутствуют Null?

Comment: Связь создать можно. Но записи, имеющие NULL, будут несвязанными.

Comment: PS. В таблицу-словарь засовывать запись с NULL не требуется. А если засунете - она также будет мотаться ни к чему не привязанная.

Comment: Внешний ключ допускает NULL-значения.
Это обычная ситуация.